# react-jsonschema-form giving error when using anyOf/oneOf property

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, jsonschema

The following JSON schema is giving the error "Invalid root object field configuration:Cannot convert undefined or null to object."

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "definitions": {},
    "id": "http://example.com/example.json",
    "type": "object",
    "oneOf": [
        {
            "properties": {
                "foo": {
                    "id": "/properties/boo",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Can someone resolve the error?

Comment: do you really need a oneOf section with only one member?

Comment: The schema is valid

Comment: @bhspencer no I need more members this is just an example. Any idea as to why the form might not be accepting it? Even though they have added support of the anyOf/oneOf properties?

Comment: I cannot get a schema that uses oneOf to work with react-jsonschema-form. I suspect this isa bug in their code. I recommend post a bug report on their github page. https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form/issues